# Color merge commits differently in Git log output?

Tags: git

I currently format my Git log using the following `pretty` definition:

```
[format]
  pretty = format:%C(normal)%h %C(blue)%s %C(yellow)[%an]%C(reset)
```

This results in the output below:

[image]

Most of the time, I don't need to pay much attention to merge commits, so I have an alias that includes the `--no-merges` flag by default:

[image]

I would actually prefer for merge commit log entries to *always* be present but be colored differently from non-merge commit log entries (so I can train my eye to skip them by default).

Is it possible to color merge commit log entries differently from non-merge commit log entries? If so, how do I achieve that?

Comment: No, or not directly anyway. You could run `git rev-list` instead of `git log`, gather all the hash IDs in the order `git rev-list` lists them (should be the same as with `git log` parameters), scan them for commits, and then run individual `git log --no-walk` commands on each one with the formatting directives set as they would be for merges and non-merges. But that's painful and forces you to run the pager manually as well.

Comment: Oof, yeah, that's very manual, as you say!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a git alias, using eg. sed.

```
[alias]
    logo = "!logo(){ git log --pretty='format:<<%p>>%H %s %D' $@ | sed -e 's/<<[^ ]* [^ ]*\\( [^ ]*\\)*>>/\\x1B[36m/' -e 's/<<[^ ]*>>//' -e 's/$/\\x1B[0m/' | less -FRSX;  }; logo"
```

The `%p` specifier prints all the parents of the commit. The sed patterns recognize when there is more than one parent and replace that case with a color code. The color is reset at the end of each line.

The function wrapper and less give you the capability to pass git log parameters and restore paging, respectively.

Comment: Nice idea! Something seems a little funky on macOS; I see parts of the color codes printing out literally, so I'll need to dig into that, but the core concept makes sense!